# Jest mocking private members

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocking

In a Node/Express server, we use a repository that needs to be unit-tested using Jest.

```
//Private things
let products;
function loadProducts() {
  if (!products)
    products = fetchProductsFromSomeDbOrServiceOrWhatever()
}
function saveProducts() {
  persistPrivateProductsToADbOrServiceOrWhatever()
}

// Exported/public things
export function read() {
  loadProducts();
  return products;
}
export function add(product) {
  loadProducts();
  products.push(product);
  saveProducts();
}
```

We want to **unit** test like this:

```
import { read, add } from './productRepo';

it('can read products', () => {
  expect(read().length).toBe(5);
});
it('can add a product', () => {
  const oldNum = read().length;
  add({id:0, name:'test prod', moreProps});
  expect(read().length).toBe(oldNum+1)
});
```

You get the idea. It's not a class so we can't mess with the prototype.

Problem: How do I mock the **private** `products` and/or `loadProducts` and/or `saveProducts` so that it isn't reading from the actual data source?

Comment: _Don't?_ This is the canonical thing to not do. If you want to decouple the module from the details of the storage, _extract them_.

Comment: I'd like to see how to do that *also*. If there's any answer to the question, it would be very cool to hear. But I'm always open to better practices, @jonrsharpe. Can you give more details on how we'd decouple them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, start initializing `products` to an empty array, else tests are doomed to fail because of the null value. Also change the null check

Then parametrize your loader and saver functions so your functions can be testable. Last write tests for you loader and saver functions outside of this repo function.

```js
// assummed imports
fetchProductsFromSomeDbOrServiceOrWhatever=()=>{}
persistPrivateProductsToADbOrServiceOrWhatever=()=>{}

//Private things
let products=[];
function loadProducts(loader) {
  loader=loader || fetchProductsFromSomeDbOrServiceOrWhatever
  if (products.length==0)
    products = loader()
}
function saveProducts(saver) {
  saver=saver || persistPrivateProductsToADbOrServiceOrWhatever
  saver()
}

// Exported/public things
export function read(loader) {
  loadProducts(loader);
  return products;
}
export function add(product,loader,saver) {
  loadProducts(loader);
  products.push(product);
  saveProducts(saver);
}
```

both exported functions can now use fetch/persist functions either by importing or as arguments.

Now the remaining is the mocking loader and saver function. saver function does not change anything so it can be null or empty. but if you want to check if it is called inside, then you need to mock it.

```js
import {jest} from '@jest/globals'
import { read, add } from './productRepo';

it('can read products', () => {
  loader=jest.fn().mockReturnValue([{id:7},{id:42}])
  expect(read(loader).length).toBe(2);
  expect(loader).toBeCalledTimes(1)
});

it('can add a product', () => {
  loader=jest.fn().mockReturnValue([{id:7},{id:42}])
  saver=jest.fn()
  const oldNum = read(loader).length;
  add({id:0, name:'test prod'},loader,saver);
  expect(read(loader).length).toBe(oldNum+1)
  expect(loader).toBeCalledTimes(0)
  expect(saver).toBeCalledTimes(1)
});
```

There is a "gotcha" here. Since `productRepo` is imported once, `loader` is called in the first test but will not be called again in the second test since the first has already changed the `products`. Thus subsequent tests must take this into account when using non-class packages.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably these private functions call out to other pieces of functionality you've written yourself or imported from libraries.

```
function loadProducts() {
  if (!products)
    products = fetchProductsFromSomeDbOrServiceOrWhatever()
}
function saveProducts() {
  persistPrivateProductsToADbOrServiceOrWhatever()
}
```

Let's take `fetchProductsFromSomeDbOrServiceOrWhatever` as the example. One basic architectural consideration to make the code properly encapsulated and testable is to put this functionality in a separate module. So I would expect an import at the head of the file:

```
import fetchProductsFromSomeDbOrServiceOrWhatever from './fetchProductsFromSomeDbOrServiceOrWhatever'
```

So in this case just mock it in your test file:

```
jest.mock('./fetchProductsFromSomeDbOrServiceOrWhatever');
```

If the functionality is not extracted into a separate module this makes your code less testable; this on its own is a good reason to refactor.

Note: the other replies on this thread are correct when they say that private functions of classes should not be tested, but I think that is a slightly different issue from the one you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

you must not get access to **private** properties or methodes anyway.
instead you can provide `setter` and `getter` for your properties.
for methodes I believe you can break it into some private parts and some public parts. private parts for your actual data source and public parts that can be used in `test` either.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest implementing an initialize method on productRepo.js.

```js
export function init(data) {
  products = data
}
```

Then, you can init products with mocked data.

Also, if you can't change the file, you could use the [rewire library](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire), which lets you access non-exported functions and variables.